# Android intent Street View does not work anymore

Tags: android, android-intent, google-street-view

i used to launch an intent from my app to Maps to display a street view panorama.
Since some days when i launch the intent Maps says : "Street View isn't available here".
I try to run a new project with only the intent as [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents?hl=en) says:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.streetview:cbll=46.414382,10.013988");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

but i receive the same message.
The same coordinates in standalone Maps work fine.
Are there any changes due to third app in maps api?

Comment: Same problem Borg. Exists any issue tracker for Google Maps for Android? Should worth to forward this problem as this is definitely issue in handling intent or Google Maps side.

Comment: hi, i opened an issue https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11371&q=apitype%3AStreetView%20type%3ADefect&sort=-stars&colspec=ID Type Status Summary Internal Stars). If you clean Maps app data it works only for the first intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs from version 9.43.0 released on 21 December.
You can find and try old working versions (last working is 9.42.3) in some repositories [like this](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/maps/).

I hoped bug was corrected with latest today release (9.45.1) but it still doesn't work.

UPDATE: Today 3 February, Street view intent seems to work again, at least in version 9.44.3 of google maps.