# Open StreetView App directly on button click- android

Tags: android, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

I want to open Google Street View Android directly from my app.
Can anyone help me in doing this?

I have successfully opened the Maps app with Streeview thanks to SO but that's not what I am looking for.

I actually want to open Streetview camera directly from my app so I can take a panoramic photo.

My actual task is to develop a camera app that can take panoramic images but I couldn't find anything for that, So I am working on things can be done instead of camera app like cardboard.
Here is the link to the question that I had asked earlier- [App to capture 360 View android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249886/app-to-capture-360-view-android)

Please help in this!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41939641/android-intent-street-view-does-not-work-anymore

Comment: I already tried this, It will open Maps app with Streetview, I want to open Google StreetView app, not Maps.
But Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: check my below ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the launch intent through the `PackageManager` class:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.street");
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Note that `getLaunchIntentForPackage` returns null if the package isn't found. 
So you might want to add a null check:

```
if (launchIntent != null) {
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "StreetView not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        launchPlayStore(mContext,com.google.android.street);
    }
```

You can use the below code to navigate him to install StreetView application via play store

```
public void launchPlayStore(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName)));
        }
    }
```

You can also open Streetview camera for clicking a panoramic image from my app with the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.street", "com.google.android.street.CameraActivity")); 
//provided you should know the camera activity name 
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, you may need to add `android:exported="true"` to the Activity's `manifest` from which you are invoking the above code.

Comment: Thanks, man It works like charm!

Can u pls help me with one more thing- I want to send the user to play store if Streetview is not installed?
or some link where I can learn more about using Streetview actually I want to directly open Streetview camera for clicking a panoramic image from my app.

Meanwhile, I accept your answer.
thanks

Comment: you can easily navigate the user to play store if StreetView is not installed via `intent` and you can also open the camera activity for clicking pictures as well try searching for open custom activity via intent

Comment: check my edited answer i know its long but you can achieve what you want

Comment: intent.setComponent(new 
  ComponentName("com.google.android.street", 
  "com.google.android.street.CameraActivity"));


this doesn't work? 

App crashes with ** "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"**

Comment: Do you know any other class Activity that can be called besides com.google.android.street.CameraActivity ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.street"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

@Rajat you can use the above code to redirect the user to Google `Street View` play store page.